# What's the difference between default event handler as an anonymous function vs function name

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm modifying an a version of fancybox so that I do it bit of code before the run function.
I suppose I could put the code in the run function but I'm wondering why I can do the following
Original line that I'm concerned with:

```
D.undelegate(selector, 'touchstart.fb-start click.fb-start').delegate(selector, 'touchstart.fb-start click.fb-start', run);
```

I would like to do the following:

```
    D.undelegate(selector, 'touchstart.fb-start click.fb-start').delegate(selector, 'touchstart.fb-start click.fb-start', function(){ /*do something */ run(); });
```

Unfortunately I get a cannot load error when I try to run the run function like this.
What's the difference between having a default handler vs a function call here?  I understand that it will be used as a callback in former sense, but shouldn't it be the same here?  Or is there some default parameters being passed into run behind the scenes. I've tried pass this, i.e., run(this) but fancybox still fails. Any ideas?

Larger piece of original source:

```
// jQuery plugin initialization
     $.fn.fancybox = function (options) {
        var opts = options || {},
            selector = this.selector || '';

    function run() {


        var group = [], relType = false, relVal = $(this).data('fancybox-group');

        // Check if element has 'data-fancybox-group' attribute, if not - use 'rel'
        if (typeof relVal !== 'undefined') {
            relType = relVal ? 'data-fancybox-group' : false;

        } else if (this.rel && this.rel !== '' && this.rel !== 'nofollow') {
            relVal = this.rel;
            relType = 'rel';
        }

        if (relType) {
            group = selector.length ? $(selector).filter('[' + relType + '="' + relVal + '"]') : $('[' + relType + '="' + relVal + '"]');
        }


        if (group.length) {
            opts.index = group.index(this);

            F.open(group.get(), opts);

        } else {
            F.open(this, opts);
        }

        return false;


    }

    if (selector) {
        D.undelegate(selector, 'touchstart.fb-start click.fb-start').delegate(selector, 'touchstart.fb-start click.fb-start', run);

    } else {
        $(this).unbind('click.fb-start').bind('click.fb-start', run);
    }

    return this;

};
```

Comment: Generally speaking it's not a good idea to modify the original plugin's js files (unless you know what you are doing) but create a custom script and use the callbacks and methods provided by the plugin.

Comment: @JFk I agree, but there's nothing that I could find in API that allows me to do what I need to do, the closest would be something like onstart().

Comment: Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs callbacks TAB, `beforeLoad` or `afterLoad`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    D.undelegate(selector, 'touchstart.fb-start click.fb-start')
      .delegate(selector, 'touchstart.fb-start click.fb-start', 
        function(){
          /*do something */ 
          run.call(this); 
        });
```

You have to make sure that the "run" function gets `this` set the way it was written to expect it.  In other words, the library makes sure that the function that's invoked gets `this` set to something relevant (the fancybox object, or whatever).  When you interpose an anonymous function like that, then *your* function is also invoked like that. You need to pass on that value of `this` to the function that was already there.